# ¿Utilizar mas de un constructor en una clase?

Tags: c#, .net

Saludos. Tengo una clase llamada empleado. Esta clase tiene los 4 objetivos básicos de un CRUD. Creé un constructor que tuviera los parámetros básicos de la tabla pero no el primary key ya que es identity y se autoincrementa.

Sucede que ahora necesito el primary key para eliminar un valor de la tabla, pero cuanto instanceo el método de crear, me pide que ingrese el de empleadoID que es mi PK.

```
     {
class Empleados
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Cedula { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int Empleado_ID { get; set; }

    public Empleados()
    {

    }

    public Empleados(string nombre, string apellido, string cedula, string direccion, int empleadoid)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Apellido = apellido;
        this.Cedula = cedula;
        this.Direccion = direccion;
        this.Empleado_ID = empleadoid;
    }


    public bool registrar()
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDO, CEDULA, DIRECCION)";
        query += " VALUES (@NOMBRE, @APELLIDO, @CEDULA, @DIRECCION)";

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", Nombre);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO", Apellido);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", Direccion);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", Cedula);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Datos insertados correctamente");
        }

        catch (SqlException p)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(p.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Actualizar()
    {

        string query = ("UPDATE Empleados set NOMBRE=@NOMBRE, APELLIDO=@APELLIDO, CEDULA=@CEDULA, DIRECCION=@DIRECCION WHERE EMPLEADO_ID=@EMPLEADOID");

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", Nombre);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO", Apellido);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", Direccion);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", Cedula);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLEADOID", Empleado_ID);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Datos actualizados correctamente");
        }

        catch (SqlException p)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(p.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }

}

    }
```

Esta es mi vista de Crear, para que tengan una idea de como va todo.

```
      private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var Empleados = new Clases.Empleados(txtnombre.Text, txtapellido.Text, txtcedula.Text, txtdireccion.Text);
        Empleados.registrar();
    }
```

Comment: Si solo necesitas el ID para eliminar, crearías otro constructor donde solo le envías dicho valor e invocas al método eliminar (el cuál tendrías que implementarlo, como hiciste con el registrar y actualizar).

Comment: Entonces puedo crear cuantos constructores me de la gana, solo agregando los valores que necesite, y cuando instancee, me los adaptará automáticamente?

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo ahora, por ejemplo, estás sobre cargando tu constructor. Tienes uno que no recibe ningún parámetro y otra que si. [Sobrecarga del constructor](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=190&inicio=60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El constructor de tu clase recibe por parámetros el id, pero si no se lo vas a mandar y no lo usas en el resto de código, simplemente borralo del constructor. Puedes crear otro constructor que sea igual al que tienes pero sin recibir el id, pero no lo veo necesario.
Sustituye esto:

```
 public Empleados(string nombre, string apellido, string cedula, string direccion, int empleadoid)
{
    this.Nombre = nombre;
    this.Apellido = apellido;
    this.Cedula = cedula;
    this.Direccion = direccion;
    this.Empleado_ID = empleadoid;
}
```

por esto:

```
 public Empleados(string nombre, string apellido, string cedula, string direccion)
{
    this.Nombre = nombre;
    this.Apellido = apellido;
    this.Cedula = cedula;
    this.Direccion = direccion;
}
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta no sea considerado como un comentario, podrías incluir código de ejemplo para que el OP pueda entender mejor. Recuerda que puedes [editar tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101530/edit).

Comment: Muchas gracias @Davlio

Answer (score 1):

Todos los comentarios que te han dado los compañeros son correctos, pero yo aprovecharía recomendarte que separases la clase de acceso a datos de la de modelo. Es decir, tendrías una clase Empleado:

```
public class Empleado {
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Cedula { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int Empleado_ID { get; set; }
}
```

y luego una clase de acceso a datos que se llamase por ejemplo EmpleadosDAO solo con los métodos de acceso y a cada uno le pasarías el objeto Empleado:

```
public class EmpleadosDAO
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);

    public bool Registrar(Empleado empleado) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }

    public bool Actualizar(Empleado empleado) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }

    public bool Eliminar(int idEmpleado) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes una idea, para eliminar no tienes que llamar a la clase crear.

Solo tienes que crear un constructor que reciba el id a eliminar,

```
public Empleados(int empleadoid)
    {
        this.Empleado_ID = empleadoid;
    }
```

y tienes que tener un metodo algo asi,

```
public bool eliminar(int id)
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE ID_EMPLEADO = @ID_USUARIO;

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_USUARIO", id);           
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Datos insertados correctamente");
        }

        catch (SqlException p)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(p.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
```